# Connect CCTV Camera With BNC Cable To Computer and Make Appear As Webcam

Tags: windows-7, video, tuner-card, input, cctv

Does anyone know the best way to connect a bnc cable(I think it's called bnc), [this](http://www.allthings.com.au/Cable/diy%2030%20m%20BNC%20video%2012%20Volt%20power%20cable.gif), to a computer (windows 7) and make it appear as a webcam so that the [Vitamin D CCTV Software](http://www.vitamindinc.com/) will see it and work with it.

Thanks.

Comment: BNC is also sometimes called COAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need an adapter to convert the analog BNC video into a digital equivalent.

You could use a PCI card to maximize compatibility:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16881127001

or try a simply USB adapted:
http://www.dealextreme.com/p/bnc-to-usb-video-converter-cable-40cm-length-51935

google around for BNC to USB or PCI adapters and you'll have a ton of options. This is very possible, as well as cheaply and easily.

Comment: Thanks. So if I use a PCI card is it common for it to simply show up as a webcam?

Comment: It really depends on the card that you choose. Some will add it as a camera device similar to the way USB cams appear, other may add it as a system device (similar to a hard drive) that can be accessed with the proper software. The upside is that most cards will come with their own software for video, and things such as edge detection are fairly standard now. Wost case I'd go with the cheap USB adapter first and if it doesn't work, send it back and buy a pci-based solution.

Comment: ok thanks. Do you reckon this might work http://www.amazon.co.uk/EasyCAP-Video-Audio-Capture-Card/dp/B0011N9QNC ?

Comment: The thing is I'd really like to use the vitamin d software as I've used it before and really like it. I think that will only work if it sees it a a webcam though

Comment: Looks like it might work, and for less than 6 pounds its hard to argue with at least giving it a shot. It's just hard to tell with legacy equipment attaching to USB, and often the only way to know is to give it a shot!

Comment: ok. I'll give it a shot and let you know if it works. Thanks again

Comment: no problem...and reading the comments on that particular adapter make it look very promising. Nearly every review makes it sound like its dead-simple to use. Good luck!